# Xamarin - Picker View com lista

Tags: xamarin, lista

Estou criando um aplicativo com Xamarin Forms e me deparei com um problema. Em uma das minhas Views preciso ter um elemento preenchido com uma lista vinda de um web service. No caso, na minha ViewModel eu consegui me conectar ao web service e preencher uma lista com os objetos que peguei de lá, porém não sei como jogar isso no Picker. As minhas classes estão assim:

View:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:BuscaCidadeDestinoViewModel></vm:BuscaCidadeDestinoViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <!--Combobox-->
        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium">Selecione a Origem:</Label>
        <Picker  ItemsSource="{Binding ?????}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

Classe na pasta Model:

```
public class CidadeDestino
{
    public string DsCidadeDestino { get; set; }

}
```

E a ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<CidadeDestino> ListaCidades { get; set; }
public BuscaCidadeDestinoViewModel()
    {

        this.ListaCidades = new ObservableCollection<CidadeDestino>();          
    }

public async Task GetCidades()
    {
        Aguarde = true;
        //abre uma conexão do tipo Http
        HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();
        //retorna uma string "GetStringAsync" e é armazenada na variavel resultado
        var resultado = await cliente.GetStringAsync(urlListaCidades);
        //"Divide" a string recebida em diversos objetos e armazena na variavel cidadeJson
        var cidadeJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CidadeJson[]>(resultado);

        foreach (var cidades in cidadeJson)
        {
            this.ListaCidades.Add(new CidadeDestino
            {
                DsCidadeDestino = cidades.CidadeDestino

            });
        }
    }
```

Já verifiquei e a "ListaCidades" é preenchida corretamente com os valores contidos no web service, tanto que se eu troco na minha View o "Picker" por uma "ListView" os valores aparecem sem problemas. Agradeço desde já a quem puder ajudar.

Atenciosamente.

Answer (score 1):

Para o bem de todos e felicidade geral das nações, [**desde a versão 2.3.4-pre do Xamarin.Forms o controle `Picker` passou a ter suas principais propriedades *bindables***](https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/). Essa operação era muito mais chata antes.

Graças a essa melhoria, podemos fazer binding com a lista de opções e com o item selecionado.

Usando esse outro recurso, você pode adicionar na sua *View Model* uma propriedade para manter o item selecionado (e também não acho que seja uma boa ideia deixar a propriedade que mantem a lista com o `set` público, isso pode dar dor de cabeça).

Então, para fins práticos, sua *View Model* ficaria assim:

```
public CidadeDestino CidadeSelecionada { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<CidadeDestino> ListaCidades { get; }
public BuscaCidadeDestinoViewModel()
{
    ListaCidades = new ObservableCollection<CidadeDestino>();          
}

... // O resto do seu código
```

E na sua tela você pode fazer assim:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:BuscaCidadeDestinoViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <!--Combobox-->
    <Label FontAttributes="Bold" 
           FontSize="Medium"
           Text="Selecione a Origem"/>
    <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding ListaCidades}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CidadeSelecionada}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Espero ter ajudado.