# Recuperar item de um Picker

Tags: xamarin-forms

Estou com um projeto no Xamarin Forms e quero recuperar um item selecionado de um Picker.

O Picker esta sendo alimentado por uma lista de Objetos na sua propriedade "ItemSource" e estou mostrando os valores dessa lista com a propriedade "ItemDisplayBindind".

O que eu quero agora é enviar o item selecionado no Picker lá para minha ViewModel, alguem pode me dizer como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Nessa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/307248/78713), cuja pergunta possui um pouco mais de detalhes sobre a implementação em questão, você pode ver um exemplo de como usar esse recurso.

Basicamente, você pode usar a propriedade `SelectedItem` do `Picker` para fazer o binding com sua *View Model*.

Como você não compartilhou o código, também não sei como dar uma resposta específica, mas seria algo mais ou menos assim:

**Na *view model* criar a propriedade que representa o item selecionado**:

public class MinhaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

```
private Objeto objetoSelecionado;
public Objeto ObjetoSelecionado 
{ 
    get { return objetoSelecionado; } 
    set 
    {
        if(objetoSelecionado != value)
        {
            objetoSelecionado = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ObjetoSelecionado");
        }  
    }
}

...
```

}

**No XAML da página, fazer o `Binding` com a propriedade equivalente:**

```
<Picker SelectedItem="{Binding ObjetoSelecionado}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListaObjetos}"
        ...
        />
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá Diego, obrigado por responder. Deu certo, consegui pegar o valor selecionado na minha ViewModel, agradeço demais.

Comment: @Q.Wesley Que bom, fico feliz em poder ajudar. Bom desenvolvimento!